# Limit speed/client over wireless network with dd-wrt

Tags: wifi, router

How would I setup my LinkSys WRT54GS v7 with dd-WRT installed on so that I can limit the download/upload speed of each client over the wireless network?
(I don't want any guys to be able to download more than 50kBps).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tc](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.ratelimit.single.html) rate limiting, by running the following commands on your router (see [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Telnet/SSH_and_the_Command_Line) for details):

```
  tc qdisc add dev $DEV root handle 1: cbq avpkt 1000 bandwidth 10mbit 

  tc class add dev $DEV parent 1: classid 1:1 cbq rate 400kbit allot 1500 prio 5 bounded isolated 

  tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip dest 192.168.0.0/16 flowid 1:1
```

This limits all traffic coming from 192.168.x.y to 400 kilo**bits** per second (50 kilo**bytes** per second)

Comment: I'm not really good at Network stuff, would you please give some bits of explanation on these commands?

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: How would I modify your command if I don't want any client (not a group of clients) to get no more than 50 kilo bytes per second?

Comment: All of your clients are assigned addresses in the 192.168.x.y range, right?

Comment: Yes, but what if I have two clients of 192.168.1.x and I want each clients to get a maximum speed of 50kBps?

Comment: Then what I said will work. If you really want, you can can `192.168.0.0/16` to `192.168.1.0/24`, which will limit everyone in 192.168.1.* to 50KBps

Answer (score 0):

The paid-for version of dd-wrt offers bandwidth limiting out of the box.